# SQL Query executed in VBA is missing decimals when pasted

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm running a SQL query through a VBA macro. One of the output columns (equivalent to column K in the excel worksheet) from my query contains numbers. When the results are pasted into an excel sheet, decimals dissapear. For example, 140000.35 is pasted as 140000. I don't want to change the column format to text because I need to operate with these amounts.
Any ideas on what's happening and how to solve it?

This is my VBA code:

```
Sub RunQueryAllocation()
 
 ' Optimization disabling features
 With Application
     .ScreenUpdating = False 'Disable screen updating
     .Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'Disable automatic calculation
     .EnableEvents = False 'Disable events
 End With
 
 'Clear destination worksheet
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1.Asignacion colateral").Range("B3:J6000").ClearContents
 
 ' Set up database connection
 Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
 Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
 Dim strSQL As String
 Dim i As Long
 Dim Fecha1 As Date
 Dim Fecha_Cierre As String
 
 conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=SPRSQPC-IW-P01.bmesp.com;" _
                         & "Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
 conn.Open
    
 ' Set up SQL query
strSQL = "" ' my query string
 ' Execute SQL query
rs.Open strSQL, conn
 
 ' Paste output into Excel worksheet
 With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
     For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
         .Cells(2, i + 1).Value = rs.Fields(i).Name
     Next
         Range("A3").CopyFromRecordset rs
 End With
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns.AutoFit
 
 ' Clean up
 rs.Close
 Set rs = Nothing
 conn.Close
 Set conn = Nothing
 
 ' Reactivate features
 With Application
     .ScreenUpdating = True 'Enable screen updating
     .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic 'Enable automatic calculation
     .EnableEvents = True 'Enable events
 End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Is there any chance that the formatting of the columns is set to show no decimals. Like the decimal exists, it's just not displayed. Clicking the `increase decimal` button in the `home` tab inside the `number` section may resolve.

Comment: No. It just paste the numbers without decimals, like it's truncating them.

Comment: Does the data in the recordset contain the full value?  If you debug.print the values are you seeing the decimals?

Comment: Hello. Yes. If I run the query on SQL Server the recordset shows the values with decimals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you change the data type to decimal and try it again. In the link below you can find some more info.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/decimal-data-type